# access function in iframe from cross domain parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have done some research on this and what i found was in same domain's case you can use

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.function_name()
```

I tried this on cross-domain (just experimenting)
It gave a cross domain error &

> Exception: TypeError: Property 'function_name' of object [object Window] is not a function

So I have a three part question

a) It is understandable if I have trouble accessing parent from child (and I am already handling this, using another iframe(from parent's domain) within child iframe).
But why do we have issue accessing child from parent, isn't that the same thing as having a

b) When I debug, using the chrome inspector tool & try to see the value of `document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow`, I see my function_name under it, but cannot access it by `document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.function_name()`. Why is that?

c) How do I successfully call a javascript function in my iframe from the parent(without easyXDM or any other plugin)?

More details:
I am more of looking for two way communication as in, my parent will call a function in iframe that returns a result & based on that result the parent will decide if it wants to redirect or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used postMessage. Seemed like a simpler solution.

What I wanted to do:
'beforeunload', send a message to child iframe, receive a response as callback. based on response show message or navigate.

But this was not possible.

This is how I solved it:

Every time a change was made in my child frame, I sent a message to the parent.
I collected these messages & used them on 'beforeunload' to decide if i should navigate or show the message

Answer (score 0):

You can use location.hash polling. Where your parent changes the URL #hash and the child checks for changes in a setInterval loop. http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-domain-iframe-communication-without-location-polling

You'd be essentially reinventing the wheel with regards to "easyXDM".

Comment: I am more of looking for two way communication as in, my parent will call a function in iframe that returns a result & based on that result the parent will decide if it wants to redirect or not. I will explore your suggestion deeper to check if I can find a solution to my problem